# ngScenario: What is the difference between browser().window() and browser().location()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, angularjs-e2e

I am learning about end-to-end testing with AngularJS and have been reading about the Angular Scenario Runner (ngScenario), the API of which is described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

My question is simple, as in the title.

Per the docs linked above, the `browser().location()` methods return the result of the corresponding method of the `$location` service.

So, for example:

- `browser().location().path()` returns `$location.path()`, whereas
- `browser().window().path()` returns `window.location.pathname`

In the [docs for the `$location` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location), we are told that:

> The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on the window.location) and makes the URL available to your application.

Thus they both seems to ultimately resolve to the `window.location` object.

What difference am I missing, and when would you use one rather than the other?